# A characterization of Grothendieck spaces via convex block subsequences

Tags: banach-spaces

Recall that $(y_{n})_{n}$ is a convex block subsequence of a sequence $(x_{n})_{n}$ in a Banach space $X$ provided that there exists a strictly increasing sequence of positive integers $(k_{n})_{n}$ so that $y_{n}\in \textrm{co}(x_{i})_{i=k_{n-1}+1}^{k_{n}}$ for every $n$ ($k_{0}=0$).

Let us recall that a Banach space $X$ is a Grothendieck space if each $weak^{*}$-null sequence in $X^{*}$ is weakly null. If $X$ is a Grothendieck space and if $(x^{*}_{n})_{n}$ is a $weak^{*}$-null sequence in $X^{*}$, it follows from Mazur's Theorem that $(x^{*}_{n})_{n}$ admits a convex block subsequence $(y^{*}_{n})_{n}$ that converges to $0$ in norm. I want to know whether the converse is true.

Question. Let $X$ be a Banach space so that each $weak^{*}$-null sequence in $X^{*}$ admits a convex block subsequence that converges to $0$ in norm. Is $X$ a Grothendieck space?

Thank you!

Comment: I suppose you meant to say that “...$X$ is a Grothendieck space if each _**weak*-null**_ (rather than _weak-null_) sequence in $X^*$ is _weakly null_.”

Comment: Thanks, Jack. I have made those corrections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be such that every weak*-null sequence $(x_n^*)$ in $X^*$ admits a convex block sequence which is norm-null.  Since subsequences of weak*-null sequences are again weak*-null, by the converse to Mazur it follows that $(x_n^*)$ is weakly null.

Comment: Thanks, Ben. But what is the converse to Mazur ?

Comment: @DongyangChen Mazur says that every subsequence of a weakly null sequence in a Banach space $X$ admits a norm-null convex block sequence. Conversely, if $(x_n)$ is not weakly null, then there are $x^*\in X^*$, $\varepsilon>0$, and a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$, such that $x^*(x_{n_k})>\varepsilon$ for all $k$.  This prevents there from being any norm-null convex block sequence of $(x_{n_k})$.

Comment: You are right, Ben.